# How to make changes to pam config such that further execution of authconfig will not overwrite them?

Tags: centos, security, configuration, authentication, pam

I'm configuring a CentOS7 host (through ansible) running `authconfig`. Now I need to add/configure `pam_exec` module to the setup but it seems it is not supported by `authconfig` (cf. [man authconfig](https://linux.die.net/man/8/authconfig) and `/etc/sysconfig/authconfig`).

I'm afraid (as mentioned in some /etc/pam.d/*conf headers) subsequent authconfig call will overwrite my changes.

How do I integrate a specific pam config to RedHat `authconfig` framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`authconfig` will only change the PAM configuration in the `/etc/pam.d/*-ac` files. Those files are not included directly into the configuration of individual services, but via a symbolic link. For example, `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac` is by default linked as `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`, and the `include` lines in files like `/etc/pam.d/sshd` or `/etc/pam.d/login` will always use the name `system-auth`, never `system-auth-ac`.

`man authconfig` says that if the symbolic links are modified, `authconfig` won't re-link them. So this is one place where system administrators can inject their own settings.

You have two options:

- Add your `pam_exec` to the PAM configuration files of the individual services, either before or after the appropriate `include` lines. This is the recommended option if you want your `pam_exec` to apply only with specific services. (Do you really need your `pam_exec` to run when an user runs `chfn` to update their own name/office/phone number information?)
- Or replace the appropriate `include` link with an actual file that has your `pam_exec` and then `include` lines referring to the corresponding `*-ac` file.

For example, if you want your `pam_exec` to run with all services that use `password-auth`, you could replace the `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` symlink (that points to `password-auth-ac` which is modified by `authconfig`) with a file like this:

```
auth include password-auth-ac
account include password-auth-ac
password include password-auth-ac
session include password-auth-ac
session required pam_exec.so <your parameters>
```

... assuming that you want your `pam_exec` in the end of the session phase. If you want to place it into a different phase, edit to suit your needs.